# Compiling Wine 1.3.6 from source on Ubuntu 14.04 (32-bit)

Tags: wine

I need to compile Wine 1.3.6 from source, but here's what I receive as an error:

```
gcc -c -I. -I. -I../../include -I../../include  -D__WINESRC__ -DINCLUDEDIR="\"/usr/local/include/wine\""   -Wall -pipe -fno-strict-aliasing -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wstrict-prototypes -Wtype-limits -Wwrite-strings -Wpointer-arith  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=0  -o parser.tab.o parser.tab.c
parser.y: In function ‘rsrcid_to_token’:
parser.y:2882:15: error: ‘YYLEX’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   lookahead = YYLEX;
               ^
parser.y:2882:15: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
make[1]: *** [parser.tab.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/trinity/wine-1.3.6/tools/wrc'
make: *** [tools/wrc] Error 2
```

I've tried to `sudo apt-get remove bison`, and then to install bison 2.5 with `dpkg`, but the error stays the same.